# drupal 7 link taxonomy term with users

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

How can i add all my users to a taxonomy term author so that when you start typing an author name it will suggest you names of all users with those letters?

Comment: Could you rewrite so we can understand it, I'm lost with what you wrote.

Comment: Change the question.

Comment: You need to install [Entity Reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. And add am entity reference field instead of taxonomy term. Users are not taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the entity [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) Module.

- Add a field with **Entity Reference** and a widget of **Auto complete (tag style)**

For example: I named mine lalala (click picture below to enlarge)

[image]

**4)** In your field settings:

- Select User as your target type

[image]

After you click save field settings you are taken to another screen, scroll down and find **Number of values** and change it to **Unlimited** and Save Changes.

[image]

On your entity reference field since we are using Autocomplete (tag style) you start to type a user name and select the user. Then add a comma `,` to add more users

Ex: [image]

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you can simply select all the users
from users table and create a taxonomy term.
Ex. `select * from users;`
then use `taxonomy_term_save()` [reference here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7) to create a term.

And if you want to create a term for every user creation.
use `hook_user_insert()` then create a term by `taxonomy_term_save()`.